# Ubuntu MATE black screen after boot

Tags: dual-boot

I just finished setting up a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10 on my HP G6, and I ran into a really frustrating problem. Ever since I finished the install, my screen goes black right after I choose Ubuntu and it finishes loading. I can bypass by changing around the quick splash in grub. Or by opening in recovery and them proceeding to launch normally.

I assume it has something to do with my drivers but they're all active in additional drivers. So it's probably something I need to either change in grub that will stay permanently or find a driver update online.

I'm really new to Linux so any help is really appreciated. Very excited to get into this OS and have some fun. Thanks.

Comment: This exact issue seems to be a reoccurring theme today... Maybe an incompatibility with Windows 10?

Comment: Weird. Well I would think that but I'm pretty sure it's just graphic related because I can hear Ubuntu noise in background, like the screen is the only thing not working. But of course I'm probably wrong and it's something more serious. I just hope not.

Comment: What happens if when you are on the back screen, you switch to the terminal (CTRL + ALT + F1) and then switch back to the desktop? (CTRL + ALT + F7)

Comment: Just tried it. Nothing. I can hear the sound as I keep hitting escape so I know it's open. Damn. Thanks though

Comment: And I know the operating system is working, I just pressed my power button quickly to bring up the shutdown window and hit enter and it went through the process normally and my computer shutdown. So everything is working I just can't see it.

Comment: Do you have Intel, AMD, or Nvidia graphics?

Comment: AMD A6-3420M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, boot to recovery mode and drop to a root shell.

1) Mount the file system as R/W: `mount -o remount,rw /`

2) Next, run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

3) Then add `nomodeset` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Becomes:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

And then save by hitting Ctrl+O, then exit nano with Ctrl+X

4) Finally, run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Ok I'm there and added nomodeset. Hit ctrl O to save. It takes me to bottom and says File Name to Write: /etc/default/grub   I then hit enter and it says read only file system. I'm not sure how to get back out of it.           Ok never mind I think I've got it. Trying now

Comment: It wouldn't let me do the sudo update part at end. Said was read only. So I rebooted and it didn't work. I probably did something wrong I guess. Thanks for that. I think that's what I need to do. If I can do correctly.

Comment: @Walt I have added a step that remounts the filesystem as R/W.

Comment: Dude... Dude! Thank you! Ha. As of a week and a half ago I didn't even know what a Linux was and now I'm WarGames'n it up   Can't wait to really get into it now. But expect more from me I'm sure                        Thanks to everyone that responded.

Comment: @Walt - If it worked, please mark my post as answer :)

Comment: I tried immediately after. I don't have enough rep I guess. Not sure how to get it. But as soon as I do I've got this bookmarked.  Also I just tried to download chrome from welcome software center and it fails each time. Says check internet connection but it's fine. Doing the software updates to see if that resolves it. I'm sure this belongs on another thread but I'm hoping this fixes.

Comment: @Walt - To mark as an answer: http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Stills working (Ubuntu 20.04 on virtualbox, installed Mate-desktop over Terminal)