# Black screen after boot (with backlight)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I use an Asus S500CA, previously installed Windows 8.1 and just installed a dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04

At the first time it was fine, everything was normal. Then I rebooted, and the GRUB menu showed up, I chose Ubuntu, the purple screen with Ubuntu logo appeared for about 2 seconds, then turned off and froze at the black screen.

The backlight was still on, but the screen just didn't show anything. Ctrl + Alt + F1 showed no result.

When I choose Windows Boot Manager at the GRUB menu, Windows 8.1 booted just fine.

I already turned off the Secure Boot, as well as enabled the CSM Boot. Can anyone help me with this case?

I tried the method in [Ubuntu MATE black screen after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746080/ubuntu-mate-black-screen-after-boot), and now, it freezes at the Ubuntu logo screen instead of black screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu MATE black screen after boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/746080/ubuntu-mate-black-screen-after-boot)

Comment: I did as the instruction, and now, instead of freezing at the black screen, it freezed at the Ubuntu logo screen.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I reinstalled the Ubuntu and everything is fine again.
Don't know what had happened though.