# Random unresponsive blank screen after boot

Tags: 16.04

Can I turn off something to stop the blank screen appearing or is this the kind of problem that needs to be reported as a bug?

The screen becomes 100% blank, at some point between the BIOS screen and the login page being displayed. The black/blank screen never goes away, pressing various key combinations does not work, not even multiple consequent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

This happens only sometimes, after pressing hard reset key on the box it boots OK and works just fine, most of the time system works fine, once it boots it works perfect. Running 16.04 for a month, this happened randomly about 6 times.

Problem never occurred immediately after an update or upgrade, it is not fresh installation.

```
sudo lshw -C video   *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:155 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

[Here is pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16703853/) of my `journalctl -b -1` from the problem boot.

I could not try login with ssh into the PC works, this week I have no other PC in my office on same network to try with.

Comment: Try adding the `nomodeset` parameter, as I have detailed here: http://askubuntu.com/a/746104/518562

Comment: `nomodeset` parameter made my graphics unusable, it did boot, but I could see screen reload from top to bottom it was as loading huge image on very slow internet connection.

Comment: It was worth a try. Linux support for Skylake is pretty bad :(