# I can't seem to install Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: system-installation, acer, dvd, aspire

I'm trying to install a newer version on a nettop (Acer Aspire Revo) that is running an older version. I have an external DVD drive that appears to be booting up ok, but when I get to the "Install Ubuntu" page, the display just goes off! The DVD drive still wizzes around for a bit and then nothing!

Any ideas?

Comment: no, I don't get that far. Just the the screen with "try Ubuntu - install Ubuntu" and so on...

Comment: Does your computer have an Nvidia graphics chip? Also, does it have a Kaby Lake CPU?

Comment: Hi, not sure about the CPU, don't think so. I believe that I do have an Nvidia graphics chip

Comment: yes, i think that i do have an Nvidia graphics chip

Comment: Try booting with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter.

Comment: my Nvidia graphics driver is 195.36.24

Comment: OK, I'll try that

Comment: Try booting with the nomodeset kernel parameter that's done the trick! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments on the question, adding the `nomodeset` kernel parameter was required to fix the issue.

NB: If you have the same issue when booting your fresh install, then you'll need to follow the steps detailed in my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/746104/518562

---

So you ask, what exactly does this parameter do and why does it fix the black screen issue?

> The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into the kernel.
>   So all the programming of the hardware specific clock rates and
>   registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than in the X
>   driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to have high
>   resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker free
>   transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on some
>   cards this doesn't work properly and you end up with a black screen.
>   Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video
>   drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

The above was excerpt from [this Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

Comment: hi, thanks for your help thus far. So I've managed to install Ubuntu, but now I have no sound and the graphics are really bad. In fact, I can't see mt graphics card to change the screen size or resolution.

Comment: any ideas on how to fix this??

Comment: @KevinWilson As this is a Q&A site and not a forum, you should post another question. Please be sure to include your computer's specifications, including the CPU and graphics chip model.

Comment: hi, thanks for that. I can't actually get in to my computer to provide said information. But, I'll post another question anyway.