# Low Graphic Mode or Blackscreen with nvidia gpu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

**Update:**

I have a pc with an Intel gpu onboard, which ran good for about two years.
Now I bought a Geforce GTX 1060 and when I want to start in Ubuntu 16.04 (I also have win 10 installed), I either get a blackscreen (if I try to start normal) or it loads the "low graphic mode", when I start over the failsafe mode.

I have the problem that it doesn't want to start the nvidia-driver even though I installed nvidia-375 and nvidia-settings. Here some more information:

(Is there a way to pack this whole log in a spoiler?)

`Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
rc  nvidia-304     304.135-0ubu amd64        NVIDIA legacy binary driver - ver
ii  nvidia-375     375.66-0ubun amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 37
un  nvidia-common   none         none        (no description available)
un  nvidia-driver-  none         none        (no description available)
un  nvidia-legacy-  none         none        (no description available)
un  nvidia-libopen  none         none        (no description available)
un  nvidia-libopen  none         none        (no description available)
un  nvidia-libopen  none         none        (no description available)
un  nvidia-opencl-  none         none        (no description available)
rc  nvidia-opencl- 304.135-0ubu amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-opencl- 375.66-0ubun amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
un  nvidia-persist  none         none        (no description available)
ii  nvidia-prime   0.8.2        amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-setting 361.42-0ubun amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA g
un  nvidia-setting  none         none        (no description available)
un  nvidia-vdpau-d  none         none        (no description available)`

---

File: /var/log/Xorg.1.log

`[    27.893] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    27.893] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    27.897] (II) Loader magic: 0x559e2cab0dc0
[    27.897] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    27.897]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    27.897]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    27.897]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    27.897]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    27.898] (++) using VT number 7
[    27.898] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    27.898] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    27.899] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0412:1458:d000 rev 6, Mem @ 0xf7800000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    27.899] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    27.899] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    27.899] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    27.914] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    28.021] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    28.021]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    28.021]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    28.021] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    28.021] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    28.021] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[    28.021] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    28.021] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    28.021] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    28.021] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    28.021] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    28.021] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so`

---

Even when it would load the nvidia driver first, it says that it can't find the nvidia module.
So I think I now have two questions:
1. How can I change the 'load-order' for my drivers?
2. What are possibilities why it can't find the module 'nvidia'?

---

I noticed that I don't have the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf, at least not exactly named like that. My file is named xorg.conf.06252017. Does that matter?

Comment: Have you tried booting with `nomodeset`?

Comment: No. How do I do that?

Comment: My answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/746104/518562) details the process.

Comment: I folowed your instructions but I still get a blackscreen when I want to start Ubuntu normally :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by downloading 'nvidia-381' and editing my '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'.
I inserted:

- ModulePath   /usr/lib/nvidia-381/xorg
- ModulePath   /usr/lib/xorg/modules

in the section 'Files' and I the section 'Device' which resembled my gpu, I edited the driver to 'nvidia-381'.

But now I get [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930919/stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-drivers-for-gtx-1060)