# Stuck in Login-loop after installing drivers for GTX 1060

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, login

After I solved [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928211/low-graphic-mode-or-blackscreen-with-nvidia-gpu?noredirect=1#comment1468727_928211), I was able to go to the login screen.
My problem now is that I am stuck in a login-loop...

Details about what led to the login-loop problem:

- bought a Nvidia GTX 1060
- installed the gpu with driver nvidia-381 on Ubuntu 16.04

Note:

- I can access the TTY while I'm in the login screen
- The login-loop: I can login perfectly but after about 5-10 seconds or so, I get thrown back to the login screen
- Most of the time this problem is solved, when you uninstall the nvidia drivers but I can't uninstall the them because without it I get my first problem again and with that blackscreens or the low-resulution mode
- Secure boot is already disabled
- Till now I haven't blacklisted nouveau, but I will try that

[I also looked at this post and some of the links there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816535/login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04)

---

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.66  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Mon May  1 15:45:32 PDT 2017


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath     "/usr/lib/nvidia-381/xorg"
    ModulePath     "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia-381"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: It's disabled since I own the pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some hours of research I found [this guide](http://abhay.harpale.net/blog/linux/nvidia-gtx-1080-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/), which helped me solve my problem.
I don't exactly know what caused my problems but now I everything works just fine.